# iOS Notifications - my devices receive notifications, testers do not

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

Please note in advance, I'm new to iOS notifications.

I'm building an iOS app which receives APNS notifications. I've provisioned the app, generated development and deployment certs and handed those to the people developing the CMS which the app consumes data from and which sends the notifications.

When the CMS sends an APNS notification, both my iOS test devices receive it. It seems to work!

I've put the app on Apple's TestFlight service, and when the app is downloaded from TestFlight to **the same 2 iOS devices** (first deleting the builds installed by Xcode), the notification are received. So that works too.

BUT.

My client has installed the app (same TestFlight build), but they aren't receiving the notifications. So I got a colleague to install TestFlight, and added her to my external testers list to install the app. The app on her iPhone ALSO doesn't receive notifications.

So for some reason, my two devices receive notifications, and as far as I can tell, no other devices do.

I'm in the process of adding tons of alert dialogs in my notification pathways to noisily alert errors.

But in the mean time, does this ring any bells to anybody? Are my two devices somehow "blessed" because I *initially* installed the app via Xcode?

Comment: The APNS certificate was generated in production mode? I also have to ask If your certificate is for production (it's supposed that you cant submit an app without the prod cert)?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the server side was the issue - when they switched to the production certs, they didn't switch to the production APNS API endpoint.

So, if anybody finds this through google, ad the above to your checklist of things-that-might-have-gone-wrong.